# Flutter widget Alignment

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to align the (+,-) icons and `TextField` on same `Vertical` Position. But i'm not getting this. 
Here is My Code.

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
             InkWell(
                  child: Icon(Icons.remove ,color: Colors.white),
                  onTap: (){},
                     ),
                     Container(
                               width: 35,
                               height: 40,
                               child: TextField(
                                      inputFormatters:[WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(digit_Reg_Expression))],
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      cursorColor: Colors.green,
                                      controller: Controler_size[index],
                                               ),
                              ),
                                      InkWell(
                                              child: Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.white),
                                              onTap: (){},
                                             )
                      ],
)
```

Please Help me to position these `Widgets` Vertically so that they align in the same vertical position.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY94T.jpg)

Comment: try Column instead of Row. let me know do you want that or something else.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place elements `vertically`, use the `Column` widget.
If you want to place elements `horizontally` use the `Row` widget.

Check the code below: It works perfectly:

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
             InkWell(
                  child: Icon(Icons.remove ,color: Colors.white),
                  onTap: (){},
                     ),
                     Container(
                               width: 35,
                               height: 40,
                               child: TextField(
                                      inputFormatters:[WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(digit_Reg_Expression))],
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      cursorColor: Colors.green,
                                      controller: Controler_size[index],
                                               ),
                              ),
                                      InkWell(
                                              child: Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.white),
                                              onTap: (){},
                                             )
                      ],
)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please see the linked attached first to know what i actually want

Answer (score 0):

set mainAxisAlignment to MainAxisAlignment.center

Comment: Please see attached link first to know about my issue

Comment: i also tried it but using  CrossAxisAlignment.end i solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I followed the link you attach in the question, I think the problem is at your Container which wraps the TextField:

```
Container(...
   width: 35,
  ---> remove this: (height: 40) ...
)
```

Comment: I removed height of container but still same issue

Comment: @HabiburRehman Another way, you may try to fix the height of (+) sign and (-) sign, set their height to 40, hope this can help